# Example of LUC algorithm with Crypto++

Tags: c++, cryptography, crypto++

I am looking for an example of LUC algorithm, but I can't find anything. I know that it is in Crypto++, but I don't know C++ too well to use it.

Comment: [LUC Cryptography](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/LUC_Cryptography) has been added to the Crypto++ wiki. It was based on the RSA page (a lot of copy/paste with find/replace).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I look for an example of algorithm of LUC...

It kind of depends on what you want to do. You might want to browse [`luc.h`](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/luc_8h_source.html) to see some of the things Crypto++ offers for LUC. There's a `LUCES`, a `LUCSS` and a `LUC_IES`. The `*ES` is encryption scheme, the `*SS` is a signature scheme, and the `*IES` is an integrated encryption scheme (which includes a key agreement algorithm and mask function).

Generally speaking, LUC is a public key encryption system. Using it is like using any other public key encryption system offered by Crypto++. That's because all the public key encryption systems inherit from the same classes (more correctly, base interfaces). You can see the design in the comments for file [pubkey.h](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/pubkey_8h_source.html).

```
$ grep -R LUCES *
...
typedef LUCES<OAEP<SHA> >::Decryptor LUCES_OAEP_SHA_Decryptor;
typedef LUCES<OAEP<SHA> >::Encryptor LUCES_OAEP_SHA_Encryptor;
```

And that's pretty much all you need, though you may not know it.

Here's the easier problem to solve. How do you perform RSA encryption in Crypto++?

```
$ grep -R RSAES *
...
typedef RSAES<PKCS1v15>::Decryptor RSAES_PKCS1v15_Decryptor;
typedef RSAES<PKCS1v15>::Encryptor RSAES_PKCS1v15_Encryptor;

typedef RSAES<OAEP<SHA> >::Decryptor RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Decryptor;
typedef RSAES<OAEP<SHA> >::Encryptor RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Encryptor;
```

If you find an `RSAES_PKCS1v15_Decryptor` or `RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Decryptor` example, you just copy/replace with `LUCES_OAEP_SHA_Decryptor` and it will work just fine. And if you find an `RSAES_PKCS1v15_Encryptor` or `RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Encryptor` example, you just copy/replace with `LUCES_OAEP_SHA_Encryptor` and it will work just fine.

You can find the examples of using `RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Encryptor` and `RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Decryptor` on the Crypto++ wiki page for [RSA Encryption Schemes](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/RSA_Cryptography#Encryption_Schemes). Or you can use the ECIES examples at [Elliptic Curve Integrated Encryption Scheme](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Ecies) (remember, all the public key systems inherit from the same base interfaces, so they all have the same methods and you use them the same way).

---

This should get you started. It creates a private key, saves it, then creates a public key, and saves it.

```
try
{
    AutoSeededRandomPool prng;

    FileSink fs1("lucs-private.der", true);
    FileSink fs2("lucs-public.der", true);

    InvertibleLUCFunction params;
    params.GenerateRandomWithKeySize(prng, 2048);

    LUC::PrivateKey privateKey(params);
    privateKey.DEREncode(fs1);

    LUCES_OAEP_SHA_Decryptor decryptor(privateKey);
    // ...

    LUC::PublicKey publicKey(params);
    publicKey.DEREncode(fs2);

    LUCES_OAEP_SHA_Encryptor encryptor(publicKey);
    // ...      
}
catch(CryptoPP::Exception& ex)
{
    cerr << ex.what() << endl;
}
```

If you don't want to use `InvertibleLUCFunction`, the do something like this to generate the key. ***Note***: RSA has an `InvertibleRSAFunction`.

```
LUC::PrivateKey privateKey;
privateKey.Initialize(prng, 2048);
...

LUC::PublicKey publicKey(privateKey);
...
```

An here's yet another way to do it:

```
FileSink fs1("lucs-private.der", true);
FileSink fs2("lucs-public.der", true);

LUCES_OAEP_SHA_Decryptor decryptor;
decryptor.AccessKey().Initialize(prng, 2048);
decryptor.AccessKey().DEREncode(fs1);
...

LUCES_OAEP_SHA_Encryptor encryptor(decryptor);
encryptor.AccessKey().DEREncode(fs2);
...
```

And here's a dump of the private key created by the test program:

```
$ dumpasn1 lucs-private.der 
  0 662: SEQUENCE {
  4   1:   INTEGER 0
  7 257:   INTEGER
       :     00 B8 7A CA 6A 61 D9 CF 2F D8 89 5C A4 7D 74 7B
       :     AC F5 10 4C 3D 95 BF DD 2E F5 4E E5 F4 20 CF CD
       :     44 7F C7 27 41 48 6B 83 E0 7C D9 66 16 8D 54 36
       :     97 B9 CE 2D 80 A6 F6 E5 25 87 83 6E B9 41 45 DC
       :     2A EB EC 4E EC D9 C0 17 B4 E0 04 F0 58 61 60 F8
       :     87 18 27 16 58 BA 56 4E DD 9B C8 CD 18 46 28 38
       :     A2 6A A6 14 36 D0 A6 FF 9C B8 A8 B5 0F 3A 11 B5
       :     00 08 44 B3 31 58 AF 01 F8 57 17 E8 FC 68 B2 5F
       :             [ Another 129 bytes skipped ]
268   1:   INTEGER 17
271 129:   INTEGER
       :     00 C8 DF 47 D0 B2 6F C2 1A E4 B7 E8 3D 12 BB FF
       :     04 F7 34 40 A0 0E ED DC F7 24 7B D9 46 EE 10 C4
       :     D5 E2 9C 93 05 CF 13 53 40 F4 50 EC 1F 6D D7 33
       :     FF FF 46 42 88 8D FC F4 EE 7F 0C 8B 71 71 51 D2
       :     3C 32 E3 9A 11 B7 D8 CF EA 10 B2 07 49 3F 93 CD
       :     A0 3F 71 A9 23 27 35 1F 6A C9 1D FE CE 24 75 33
       :     8F 53 71 B9 0B DE BC 05 93 98 A3 EA 94 8E 04 B1
       :     29 A1 4F 4C 82 34 7A 08 3A 0E 07 98 8B 00 30 D7
       :     5B
403 129:   INTEGER
       :     00 EB 1B D0 EF 5C 0F FC FC B7 56 A7 70 8C AA B7
       :     A6 90 C8 1F AA AD A0 0B 66 E5 33 75 F2 BE 68 35
       :     29 2E 57 AC E0 E0 C8 04 A7 C4 13 1D 10 30 8B 50
       :     20 17 0C 83 A7 14 4A 7D 25 31 77 50 66 08 36 13
       :     BE 9D C0 4E F4 44 74 7A BB D2 92 D0 F7 AE 7C EB
       :     8E 84 5C 27 61 2C C9 7A D1 D0 C5 A0 13 98 96 E3
       :     76 CD B0 E7 E8 7E 4E 0A 2D 00 86 07 57 DB 8A 51
       :     1E 59 76 EA 88 44 4D DA F3 D6 AB 75 CB A6 45 F3
       :     F3
535 128:   INTEGER
       :     2E 6A AA BA B4 E8 DD 11 2D 31 A4 D5 F7 08 AB E3
       :     1A 9A 15 58 AE C8 59 BE C4 75 85 90 6D 5D A4 18
       :     39 27 8F FF 1C 9A FD 0F 0C 29 05 98 9C 16 FE 84
       :     A4 5C 85 15 F7 98 E6 D5 5B 23 CA 2F A2 27 8A 00
       :     6E B1 BB 02 6E 93 53 85 30 30 61 F5 1C 49 5D 19
       :     EF DF CD 6F 11 7C 6D DC AE F6 A2 06 53 BB 7E 03
       :     C3 E5 4E E9 59 E0 D8 5F C3 28 0E E0 17 5C 63 6E
       :     8E A6 18 FC AD A5 9B 08 D1 8B 7B 28 9D E2 CF E2
       :   }

0 warnings, 0 errors.
```

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer.  Just right, that's it.